# Event Viewer works but logparser fails?

Tags: windows, logging, windows-server-2016, logparser, centralized-logging

So, my Log Parser Query fails and states that the remote procedure call failed.

However, I am able to connect using the Event Viewer (which I hate); what does the event viewer use to connect that the log parser does not?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2>LogParser -e:1 "SELECT EventId, RecordNumber, EventId, SourceName, TO_STRING( TO_UTCTIME( TimeGenerated ), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ll' ), Strings INTO 'C:\l*.csv' FROM \\DC1\Security, \\DC2\Security, \\DC3\Security WHERE TimeGenerated >= TO_LOCALTIME( SUB( SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP(), TIMESTAMP( '1', 'd' ) ) ) AND EventId=4740 ORDER BY RecordNumber DESC"

Task aborted.
Error reading event log: The remote procedure call failed.
```